# Show thumbnails in ListView in Windows RT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I have a code to get the thumbnails, that looks like this

```
public async Task<bool> SetThumbnail(Model.FileInfo Fil)
{
   try
   {
      // Set the File
      var File = await GetStorageFile(Fil);

      // Set the File's thumbnail
      Fil.FileThumbnail = await File.GetThumbnailAsync(Windows.Storage.FileProperties.ThumbnailMode.ListView);

      // Set the File
      Fil.File = File;

      // Return true as it was successfully executed
      return true;
   }
   // Otherwise it was not successful so return false
   catch (Exception e) {
      return false;
   }
}
```

The GetStorageFile-method looks like this

```
private async Task<StorageFile> GetStorageFile(Model.FileInfo FileInf)
{
   // Create (and open the Folder)
   var Folder = await _Folder.CreateFolderAsync(_FilesFolderName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

   // Get the File
   return await Folder.GetFileAsync(FileInf.ID + "." + FileInf.Extension);
}
```

It works great 1st time, but when I show the List the second time, the Thumbnails does not show up

What could be wrong, when I run it the 2nd time?

Comment: Perhaps it's all in capitalization?

Comment: No, it is not. The Filename is the ID from the database and of course the File-extension

Comment: So let me get this straight - if you call SetThumbnail once - it works, but if you make the same call twice (await SetThumbnail(file);await SetThumbnail(file);) - the thumbnail disappears?

Comment: Is any exception caught in `SetThumbnail` when it doesn't work?

Comment: @FilipSkakun It get's the Thumbnail-object, but it can not be shown :s

Comment: @DamirArh No, there are no exceptions